# How to retain formating of text as stored in db while printing

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i am using php to get the result from the database. In database i have c code with lots of enter and tabs for better understanding.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 main()
{
printf("Hello World");
}
```

But the problem is in output i am getting output in a single line when i print it.

```
 #include main() { printf("Hello World"); }
```

How can i produce the output with proper formating as stored in db.

Comment: Its better to store these data with some html formatting, so that each time yoou extract values you get the same format.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the html `<pre>` balise to preserve the format of the text to be displayed.

Answer (score -1):

when you echo to print data use the

```
nl2br();
```

then echo the data like

```
echo nl2br($data_from_db);
```